# Qt5: How to repaint while doing a big calculation

Tags: c++, qt, widget, exec, qt5

I am writing a mathematical simulator in `Qt5` and when I click a button, some heavy calculation needs to be done. During it, I want to display a `Please, wait` window, eventually with a progress bar. Preferably without using threads.

Problem is, during calculation the application hangs, events are not handled, and what should be a `please, wait` window is merely a window frame without any contents (looks transparent).

```
PC: AMD X2 L325, 2GB RAM, Radeon E4690
OS: Debian 6 (Squeeze, Old stable)
gcc 4.4.5, Qt 5.2.0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to do heavy calculations without any UI hangings you'll have to use threads

Comment: I think using threads threads is the right solution

Comment: or you can use `QApplication::processEvents()` method inside your calculation code. Commonly its called on each iteration of some loop. Useful when you don't want to mess with threads or when its superfluous

Comment: Well, even if it's a simple calculation, the "Please, wait" window never gets painted. Can I at least get around this without using threads?

Comment: Yes, you can, but using threads or concurrency is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could call QApplication::processEvents, it's not the best approach.
If you're avoiding threads because they're new to you, then I'm sure you'll find it much easier once you've done it once. Qt makes it easy.

All you need to do is create a class derived from QObject which will do the calculations. Next, create a thread and call the object's moveToThread function. The thread is then controlled with a few signals and slots. That's all there is to it.

Rather than repeat the content here, I suggest you read [this article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), which explains it in detail and provides clean and concise example code.

From the new object that processes your calculations, it can then emit a signal to a slot on the main thread, which will update the progress on your "Please Wait" window.

Note that Widgets and all rendering must be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use [Qt Concurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html). It is not well documented, but very handy, much better then using QThread directly.

I usually do such things like that I have separate QObject for logic, in there some slot which calls heavy calculation like that (see [run documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html)):

```
void MyCalculationClass::startCalculating() {
    QtConcurent::run(this, &MyCalculationClass::doHeavyCalculation);
}
```

Where method `doHeavyCalculation` emits signals with progress and calculation results.
Usually this method operates on its own data not modified by other threads/methods, so if synchronization is needed, it is trivial. Signal-Slot mechanism is handling most of the multithreading issues (note that default connections detects that signals is emitted from other threads and queues slot calls in proper thread, it is done automatically by default).

Comment: This article's discussion of QtConcurrent would likely disagree to it being "much better than QThread": http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/7942 Also note that QThread's name is a bit misleading. It's more of a thread controller than an actual thread.

Comment: Still with `QtConcurent::run` you have less boilerplate code.

Comment: Can't argue against that!

Answer (score 0):

i have such problem and i solve it like this, i make calculation in another thread( i use std::thread instad of QThread) before i start my calculation i just start timer

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(repaint()));
timer->start(1);
```

and then

```
std::thread t(&Widget::calcBackgound, this);
t.detach();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the heavy and time consuming part of your code in `run()` member function of another class which inherits from `QThread`. After that create an instance of the new class and simply call its `start()` function.
Your new class can have a signal which emits the current progress value. you can then connect this signal to the slot of a progress bar.